# Using both $z$ and $z^*$ to represent real functions

Tags: complex-analysis

In physics and other applied disciplines, we often study infinitely differentiable real functions ${f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}}$ by considering their analytic continuation $f(z)$ and employing the fact that $\left.f(z)\right|_{\operatorname{Im}z=0}=f(x)$. This is only possible when $f(z)$ is an analytic function.

There is, however, a large number of infinitely differentiable functions which are perfectly OK from the "real perspective" but cannot be described by nice analytic functions (smth like $|x^3|$, not sure though if it's a good example for what I ask next...).

My question is whether one can make any use of considering non-analytic functions like ${F(z)=f_1(z)+f_2(z^*)}$, where both $f_1(z)$ and $f_2(z)$ are analytic and ${\left.F(z)\right|_{\operatorname{Im}z=0}=f(x)}$ in order to study the real function $f(x)$.

Obviously, most juicy theorems from complex analysis only work for analytic functions, and cannot be applied directly within such a setting. Still, I'm wondering if there's been any research regarding how we can benefit from considering complex functions of both $z$ and $z^*$ for describing the real functions.

Comment: Hmm. If we have a real function $f$ such that $f(x) = f_1(x) + f_2(x)$ with both $f_1$ and $f_2$ analytic then we can simply consider $f_1(z) + f_2(z)$ which will necessarily be analytic (since $f_1$ and $f_2$ were assumed to be) and matches $f$ on the real line, so we are back to the standard case

Comment: True. My question was more about "are there any situations when one would benefit from considering, say, expansions in both $z$ and $z^*$?"

Comment: ah. Then the answer is sorta yes. I don't know of any good reasons in single variable complex analysis, but complex manifold theory is full of such constructions. I'll see if I have time later to outline one or two. In practice we often don't study the real function this way, as the analytic continuation carries all the info, but sometimes it's cleaner to express a condition in terms of the basis $z, z^*$

Comment: Interestingly, my research from the last year used exactly what you propose: I was studying functions which preserve the real line (i.e. Real functions) by studying things of the form $\tfrac{f(z) + \bar{f}(z^*)}{2}$ which turn out to have symmetry properties that shrink strips and sectors centered on the real line (where $f$ is a given differential operator multiplied by some operation generating the set, e.g. an exponential map for a sector). I was never able to prove the conjectures I made, but I did extensive numerical calculations..

Comment: ... and I'd be happy to share further details upon request. In general, I only see sums of the form you want used to study real functions when we wish to study the geometry of the plane via actions that must be automorphisms of the real line, where we view the actions given by $f_1$ and $f_2$ as being somewhat "dual" to one another (I don't know of any interesting results when $f_1$ and $f_2$ are not in some sense dual, at least when using summation).

Comment: Those- $f(z)+g(\bar z), f,g$ complex analytic - are (complex) harmonic functions and there is a large body of theory behind them - check either the topic (complex) harmonic functions or quasi-conformal functions; not necessarily what you are interested in but there are beautiful results about polynomials of 2 real variables which are harmonic but not (complex) analytic which extend for example the fundamental theorem of algebra